# CefSharp 3.3578.1870 change background color

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, c#-6.0

I'm loading  a GIF image from file using `chromeBrowser.Load(_pathTmp);`
My current version is 3.3578.1870.
As result I'm getting this:

[image]

Is that possible to get rid of black stripes invisible for user? I want to make background of resulted web page white because my image has white background. How to achieve that? I want it to look like this:

[image]

If I'm using JS there's a flicker from black to white, because page is already loaded so script executed when user already see image.

`chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.style.backgroundColor = \"white\";");`

I checked HTML source of page, noticed background tag of body:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e;">
```

Chrome 65 And Chromium 65 sets #0e0e0e background by default for images.
[Question at Google support](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B04RQ48dDI4fU/?hl=en&msgid=nz_mXXXZBwAJ&gpf=d/msg/chrome/4RQ48dDI4fU/nz_mXXXZBwAJ)

Is that possible to configure chromium somehow via CefSharp to set body BG to #ffffff as it was in Chromium 63?

I see another option to solve my problem:

1. Hide browser control
2. Load image
3. Load Script after image loaded completely
4. When script succeeded show browser control.

But I can't implement it properly.

Excuse my language

Comment: Use [`CefSettings.BackgroundColor`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_AbstractCefSettings_BackgroundColor.htm).

Comment: I mentioned that I'm using `CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
                settings.BackgroundColor = Cef.ColorSetARGB(255, 255, 255, 255); Cef.Initialize(settings);`But it gives no effect

Comment: Don't load your GIF directly, but put it into a black HTML page.

Comment: Please don't post large amounts of code in comments, edit your original question with what you have tried.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken the `alpha` component should be either `0` or `1` depending on the desired effect, not `255`. Calling `LoadHtml` you cannot by default access the `file` scheme due to security restrictions, likely in `Chrome` or `FireFox` you are opening the file using the `file` scheme, so it can access local files. It's a subtle yet important difference.

Comment: Set `aplha` to 1, but looks like it changes color of chromium bg when there's no page loaded. So Method `Load` generates html page with black BG. It would be great to find out how to set this color without execution JS, because it gives flickering.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. Please clarify, post a more complete example of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Formatting your code would be helpful, very hard to read as it is.

Comment: I have changed my question to make it more clear, sorry again.

Comment: Thanks,  much clearer now.  Will try respond in detail later

Comment: Are you using a temp file because the image actually comes from a database? Is it just the one image you'll be showing or dynamically loading a large number?

Comment: Image comes from a database, right. There are a lot of images in db, and I'm showing them in "Power Point style", "next" button shows next image, "previous" - shows previous.

Comment: I have a few ideas, like intercepting before the page loads to modify the background color to avoid flicker like with JS. Are you directly loading the image (`image.gif` or through HTML `image.html`)?

Comment: I'm loading image directly, passing temp path of image (saved from database to temporary folder) to `chromeBrowser.Load`.